# how to plot points on function using tensorboard

Tags: python, pytorch, data-visualization, tensorboard, torch

I am trying to visualize the output of my algorithm in tensorboard.

My algorithm is outputting points and I want to see were these points are on a specific function.
To understand what I am trying to achieve I plotted the desired output in jupyter notebook
[image]

And here is the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torhc

def eggholder(w0,w1):
  a=-(w1+47)*torch.sin(torch.sqrt(torch.abs(w1+w0/2+47)))
  b=-w0*torch.sin(torch.sqrt(torch.abs(w0-(w1+47))))
  return a+b

range0, range1 = torch.linspace(0, 512, 1000), torch.linspace(0,512, 1000)
grid0,grid1=torch.meshgrid(range0,range1)

grid_cost=eggholder(grid0,grid1)
history = torch.tensor([[100,200], [150,100], [100,300]])

plt.figure(figsize=[12.8, 9.6])
plt.contourf(grid0,grid1,grid_cost,cmap="Greys");
plt.scatter(history[:, 0], history[:, 1], marker="o",color="r")
plt.show()
```

In the picture you can see my function (f:R*2 -> R) and 3 points in red that my algorithm outputted. Is it possible to draw such a thing in tensorboard?
another possibility is to draw 3d graph and to mark specific points on the graph. Is this possible?

Comment: If you're able to do it with matplotlib then you can use that in a function and just add the final rendered figure to tensorboard using `add_figure` - [docs link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html#torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter.add_figure)

Comment: The output is like an image and non of the grid support for tensorboard can be used (such as presenting scalar data when you hover over it)

Comment: Since you mentioned 3D graph, you can try to plot it as a mesh with `add_mesh` - [docs link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html#torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter.add_mesh). This is supposed to be an interactive 3D plot.